# Multiple images rename & uploading in PHP

Tags: php

I am using the following code to upload set of images into the server, I am renaming the files while uploading, but when I am trying to uploading multiple files its automatically replacing the files, instead I need the other files to be named with 2, 3, 4, etc. in the end of the file name.

```
<input type="file" name="upl" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

`$_SESSION['imgrand']` is the random string generated and passed over session.

```
function findexts ($filename) 
 { 
 $filename = strtolower($filename) ; 
 $exts = split("[/\\.]", $filename) ; 
 $n = count($exts)-1; 
 $exts = $exts[$n]; 
 return $exts; 
 } 
 $ext = findexts ($_FILES['upl']['name']) ; 
 $ran = $_SESSION['imgrand'];
 $ran2 = $ran.".";
 $target = "uploads/";
 $target = $target . $ran2.$ext; 

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 {
 echo "The file has been upl as ".$ran2.$ext;
 } 
 else
 {
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
 }
```

For example if the random string is jahkhakshdkjshdjksahds I need the images should be named as jahkhakshdkjshdjksahds1.ext, jahkhakshdkjshdjksahds2.ext, jahkhakshdkjshdjksahds3.ext, jahkhakshdkjshdjksahds4.ext, jahkhakshdkjshdjksahds5.ext likewise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test for a existing file before overright.

```
...
$ext = findexts ($_FILES['upl']['name']) ; 
$ran = $_SESSION['imgrand'];
$target = "uploads/".$ran;

for($i=1;$i < 100;$i++) {
  $filename = $target.$i.".".$ext;
  if (file_exists($filename)) {
    continue;
  } else {
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], $filename)) 
    {
    echo "The file has been upl as : ".$filename;
    break; 
    } 
    else
    {
    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file: ".$filename;
    break;
    }
  } // not file_ex
} // for
...
```